# Dialog box appear for parameter Field in Crystal Report

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports-2010

I want to pass a parameter from visual studion WinForm to crystalReport I have done this:

```
rptDoc.SetDataSource(dt);           
ParameterFields paramFields = new ParameterFields();
ParameterField paramField = new ParameterField();
ParameterDiscreteValue paramDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
paramField = new ParameterField();
paramDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
paramField.Name = "CableRevision";
paramDiscreteValue.Value = currentInfo.CableRevision;
paramField.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue);
paramFields.Add(paramField);

crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptDoc;
```

and also i have defined a Parameter Field of Field Explorer in Report Named "@CableRevision". should it be Dynamic or Static? I have tried both but every time a dialog box and asks for CableRevision Parametere Value. i dont wan't that dialog box get the value because i want to pass the value by

```
paramDiscreteValue.Value = currentInfo.CableRevision;
```

is that wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your paramField didn't connect to `rptDoc` yet.

You may try this code instead

```
ParameterFieldDefinitions crParams = rptDoc.DataDefinition.ParameterFields;
foreach (ParameterFieldDefinition def in crParams)
{
   if (def.IsLinked())
   {
      continue;
   }

   // create new Parameter Discrete Value object 
   ParameterDiscreteValue paramDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();

   string paramName = def.ParameterFieldName;
   switch (paramName)
   {
      case "@CableRevision": paramDiscreteValue.Value = currentInfo.CableRevision; break;
      case "@OtherParam": paramDiscreteValue.Value = OtherParamValue; break;
   }

   // extract collection of current values 
   ParameterValues currentValues = def.CurrentValues;

   // Add Discrete value object to collection of current values 
   currentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue);

   // apply modified current values to param collection 
   def.ApplyCurrentValues(currentValues);
}
```

**`rptDoc.DataDefinition.ParameterFields`** will return all parameters in the rptDoc. Then you have to set value for each parameter as in `switch` scope.

This is sample for many patameters in report, if you have only on parameter, you don't need to have `switch` scope, just have this line instead

```
paramDiscreteValue.Value = currentInfo.CableRevision;
```